# How we can add some same Parameters for all link in my a webform page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, hyperlink

when asp.net output a page ,I want to add some same parameters for all links() in this page
How I can do it ?

somesite.com/page.aspx => somesite.com/page.aspx?same=value

somesite.com/?anyp=hevalue => somesite.com/?anyp=hevalue&same=value

auto add same=value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are all server controls such as `<asp:LinkButton>` then you can walk the Page.Controls collection and modify them.  You would probably have much better luck doing this on the client side, however.  jQuery is great for such things.

Comment: No,I am not use any server controls, is it better on the client side do this ?

Comment: Yes and no if you use jquery it will be easy to do, but might break the application when javascript it turned off by the end user. about 2-5% of users have javascript disabled.

Comment: That's true, with a jQuery-only solution you'd cut out anyone not running javascript.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
//adding the same query string parm to all links
var parameter = "&parameter=value";
$('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', href + parameter);
});
```

Comment: <a href='http://google.com' /> <a href='http://some.com/page.aspx?somep=value /> change to <a href='http://google.com/?same=myvalue' /> <a href='http://some.com/page.aspx?somep=value&same=myvalue /> this is i want

Comment: I edited my answer - this should do it if you're not using any server controls.  I haven't tested this, but I think it's pretty close :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some coding on the .aspx page

```
<a href='<%#"http://localhost/MyPage.aspx?RoomID=" + txtNumber.Text %>'>RoomID</a>
```